# API Gateway Rate Limiting with JWT Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, rate-limiting, api-throttling

Can I create token base rate limiting for my API Gateway so that different users have different limits?

AWS cognito is used to issue the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly speaking about limiting access to your API based on different users. You can use "usage plans" in API Gateway to limit users accessing APIs by providing different API keys associated with different usage plans.
Read more here: [API Gateway Usage Plans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html)

Comment: Usage Plans use API-keys to identify users.
The default limit for API-keys is **max 10k per region**.

Any serious product would probably have more than 10k users.

Hence in my opinion, due to this limitation of **max. 10k api-keys per region** - using Usage-plans ( which **rely on api-keys to identify users** ) it not feasible to rate-limit users.